How to upload fine-tuned Mistral-7B to HuggingFace?
I have successfully fine-tuned a Mistral-7B model and would like to upload it to HuggingFace so I can deploy the model and access the endpoint via API.
I have a .pth file which is basically the outcome of the merge of my weights with the basemodel. I basically run with the lit-gpt-module to generate text as of now.
From what I know is, that I also need configuration and tokenizer,..
Any help is highly appreciated.
EDIT: I was able to use lit-gpt to basically convert it to a HF model. I just exchanged the .pth file. Although I am not 100 % sure yet, if that's the correct approach.
I'll update here once I know more.
